# How to loop through all imports from a particular file in python?

Tags: python, loops, import

I'm working on a project where I have to call in the values present in a variable from all the classes that were imported. One way to achieve it is to manually write the class names, but I wanted to know if there is some way, we can iterate through it.

Nothing, I have tried seems to work. I tried using iter_modules() but got an AttributeError. Following is a sample of the problem:

Lets say I have a folder views, where I have defined 10 different views classes in different files and the **init**.py inside the views folder as shown:

```
from .view1 import ViewClass1
from .view2 import ViewClass2
from .view3 import ViewClass3
from .view4 import ViewClass4
.
.
.
from .view10 import ViewClass10
```

Now, I in my base folder where I need to call in all the viewclasses, I have the code as shown:

```
from .views import *
# Should import all the ViewClasses ie ViewClass1, ViewClass2 and so on

# I have to call the staticmethod get_view_type defined in all the classes
# One way is:
# print(ViewClass1.get_view_type())
# print(ViewClass2.get_view_type())...
# The above continues

# But I want a solution where I can loop through all the imports from the views __init__ and call the method as:
# for viewclass in [Something]:
#     print(viewclass.get_view_type())
```

I wanted to know if there is some method to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems a little iffy from a design perspective but here you go:

```
import views
```

or

```
from . import views
```

As your imports seem relative to your `PYTHONPATH`.

```
for name, entity in views.__dict__.items():
    if not name.startswith('__'):
        cls = entity
        print(cls.get_view_type())
```

You can add more conditions on `cls` (like it being a subtype of some etherial `ViewClass` or something). A better way would be to have a list in the bottom of your views file that enumerates all the classes and you can just import that instead of messing with the internal representation of a module.